# Iteration loop for the large number of variable naming

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I want to generate a number of note in a music database, but I don't know how to use some iteration like for loop to simplify the following, I hope someone can shed some lights on me.

```
note1 = note.Note(tune_array_bass[0])
note2 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[1])
note3 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[2]) 
note4 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[3])
note5 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[4])
note6 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[5])
note7 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[6])
note8 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[7]) 
note9 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[8])
note10 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[9])
note11 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[10])
note12 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[11])
note13 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[12])
note14 =note.Note(tune_array_bass[13])
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't exactly understand what you meant but, here's my solution to list the notes using a loop:

```
class Note:
    def __init__(self,note):
        self.note = note

tune_array_bass = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
for item in tune_array_bass:
    new_notes = Note(item)
    print(new_notes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the objects in a list instead:

```
notes = []
for i in range(14):
    notes.append(note.Note(tune_array_bass[i]))
```

Then you can access each note object using `notes[0], notes[1] etc.`

Answer (score 0):

Don't create many individual variables like this.
Instead, you could use a list:

```
notes = [note.Note(tune_array_bass[i]) for i in range(14)]

# get a note from the list:
notes[0]
```

Or a dictionary:

```
notes = {f"Note{i+1}":note.Note(tune_array_bass[i]) for i in range(14)}

# get a note from the dict:
notes["Note1"]
```